# Passing two variables to sed in bash script

Tags: bash, sed

Hope someone is able to point me in the right direction here. When I'm passing two variables in sed it no longer seems to recognize the input, and therefore will not replace the string I am looking for.

Could someone please look over my syntax?

Lets assume here that

```
$netmask1="/24"

$ipaddrs="192.168.0.2 192.168.0.3
```

```
astringb=$(grep -m 1 addresses /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml)
astringa=${astringb:0:-1}
ipaddrs=$(echo $ipaddrs | sed "s| |$netmask1\,|g")

sed "s|$astringb|$astringa$ipaddrs$netmask1\]|g" /etc/netplan/01-netcfg.yaml
```

As soon as I pass variable $astringb to sed it is no longer able to identfy said string in my netplan config file. If I replace this variable with any actual text in this file it'll recognize and replace immediately.

Would appreciate any help.

Comment: What do `$astringa` and `$astringb` contain?

Comment: Please show the original line and the desired result.

Comment: The number of variables shouldn't matter. The problem must be with the values of the variables.

Comment: Lovely lad from reddit helped me fix it, the golden line; sed "s|${astringb//\[/\\[}|$astringa,$ipaddrs$netmask1\]|g"